# How to create variable count resources in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I need to create variable count S3 bucket, with name from Parameters. E.g. I have array with S3 bucket names.
def bucketNames = ["first-bucket", "second-bucket", ..., "n-bucket"].
Is it possible to do it?
Maybe with nested stack.

Comment: There isn't an official syntax for that. You could create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) for that.

Comment: I'd recommend using the AWS CDK for this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html). The CDK will generate a Cloudformation template containing all the resources needed for each bucket without having you repeating YAML code over and over.

Comment: You could also consider something like ansible to template the cloudformation file, by looping over a list of bucket names: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a custom resource:

This template will create the custom resources:

```yaml
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Description: create buckets from parameters
    Parameters:
      BucketList:
        Description: comma delimited list of bucket names
        Type: CommaDelimitedList
        Default: athos,porthos,aramis
    Resources:
      BucketCreatorLambda:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
          Handler: index.handler
          Code: ./bucketor/
          Runtime: python3.8
          Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaExecutionRole.Arn'
      CustomBucketCreator:
        Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
        Properties:
          loglevel: info
          Buckets: !Ref 'BucketList'
          RoleArn: !GetAtt 'LambdaExecutionRole.Arn'
          ServiceToken: !GetAtt 'BucketCreatorLambda.Arn'
      LambdaExecutionRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service:
                    - lambda.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                  - sts:AssumeRole
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
          Path: /
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: BucketPolicy
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - s3:CreateBucket
                    Resource: arn:aws:s3:::*
    Outputs:
      BucketsCreated:
        Description: names of buckets created
        Value: !GetAtt 'CustomBucketCreator.BucketNames'
```

and the python script for lambda :

```py
    # python file named index.py located ./bucketor/ with respect to cloudformation file
    from crhelper import CfnResource
    import logging
    import boto3
    
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    # Initialise the helper, all inputs are optional, this example shows the defaults
    helper = CfnResource(json_logging=True, log_level='DEBUG',
                         boto_level='CRITICAL', sleep_on_delete=120)
    
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    
    try:
        # Init code goes here
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, exc_info=True)
        helper.init_failure(e)
    
    
    @helper.create
    def create(event, context):
        bucket_names = []
        buckets = event["ResourceProperties"]["Buckets"]
        for bucket in buckets:
            bucket_names.append(s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket)["Bucket"])
        helper.Data.update({"BucketNames": ",".join(bucket_names)})
    
    
    def handler(event, context):
        global logger
        helper(event, context)
```

This `@helper.create` will create the buckets for you. You also will need write the appropriate `@helper.delete` and `@helper.update` decorators, if you don't the custom resource will need manual deletion

Comment: does it have to be in cloudformation? you could use terraform like so:

   variable "bucket_names" {
      description = "names for buckets"
      type        = list(string)
      default     = ["uno", "duex", "three"]
    }
    
    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "buckets" {
      count  = length(var.bucket_names)
      bucket = var.bucket_names[count.index]
    }